# Handling multiple line matches using regex

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I am reading the XML file into an array.The XML file has many free form text within it.
Is it possible to use regex to capture the data.

XML FILE:

```
  <class>
    <students>
        <student>
            <roll>1</roll>
            <name>first_name
            middle_name
            last_name</name>
            <remark>
            some free

            form text goes 
            here
            </remark>
        </student>
    </students>
</class>
```

I am trying to get the values into array as:

```
arr[0]  <class>
arr[1]  <students>
arr[2]  <student>
arr[3]  <roll>1</roll>
arr[4]  <name>first_name middle_name last_name</name>
arr[5]  <remark>some free form text goes here </remark>
arr[6]  </student>
arr[7]  </students>
arr[8]  </class>
```

I am not very sure how to handle multi line text using regex.Is regex the correct approach?

Comment: Seems like you'd prefer an XML parser? This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Which programming language are you using for this ?

Comment: @Tuga Without being sure it seems (based on his previous questions) that he's using perl, so PCRE.

Comment: Yes.. I am using Perl ...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use an XML parser which will get you most of the way to where you want to be:

```
$ perl -E 'use XML::Simple; 
    use Data::Dumper; 
    my $ref = XMLin("a.xml", NormaliseSpace => 2) ;
    print Dumper $ref;'
$VAR1 = {
          'students' => {
                        'student' => {
                                     'remark' => 'some free form text goes here',
                                     'name' => 'first_name middle_name last_name',
                                     'roll' => '1'
                                   }
                      }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression for parsing, XML.  Use an actual XML Parser.

Some good heavy weight ones are: [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) and [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig)

For a light weight module, which is good at reading not as good at writing:  [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aSimple)

Answer (score 0):

Cleanup any spaces and line breaks and your good to go.

it seems that you're using perl, so:

```
@result = $subject =~ m!((?:<.*?>)?(?:</?.*?>|\s+<remark>.*?)?(?:[\w|\s]+)?(?:\s*)?(?:</?.*?>)$)!simg;
```

**REGEX:**

```
/((?:<.*?>)?(?:</?.*?>|\s+<remark>.*?)?(?:[\w|\s]+)?(?:\s*)?(?:</?.*?>)$)/simg
```

http://regex101.com/r/xZ3vL9